# Regex to match positive or negative number or empty string, but not '-' alone

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers

I want to validate numbers in an input in Javascript.

The input should accept:

- empty input ''
- positive number '123'
- negative number '-123'

I have used this regex:

```
^(-?)[\d]*$
```

It works well, but it also accepts only the minus character alone '-' . I want to exclude this possibility. I could of course replace `*` with `+`, but that would exclude the empty string.

How can I do it so that a `-` must be followed by at least one number, but a completely empty string is still OK?

Comment: why not `isNaN()`?

Comment: You can use `/^(?:-?\d+)?$/`

Comment: @gurvinder372 It needs to be RegEx based because it's part of a larger validation system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may make the digits obligatory and enclose the whole number matching part with an optional group:

```
/^(?:-?\d+)?$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1BpV5t/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of the string
- `(?:-?\d+)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of:

  - `-?` - an optional `-`
  - `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 3):

The below regex should fulfill your requirements:

```
^(|-?\d+)$
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/7UcGv5/1)

Let's dissect the regex to understand how it works

- The outer body `^()$`: `^` denotes the start of the string and `$` signifies the end. `()` tells the matcher to capture everything enclosed. So in our case, it means that our input should be an exact match.
- `|` is a boolean **OR** i.e. returns positive if either of the regexes is satisfied.
- `-?\d+` matches the positive and negative numbers as follows

  1. `-?` matches `-` between zero and one times
  2. `\d+` matches a digit between one to unlimited times
- There is another check which essentially isn't there. If you look closely the expression does not have anything before the `|` *OR* operator. That is the null or the empty input check.
- These combined with the **OR** means that the input can either be nothing or an integer.

With all these combined, we arrive at the required regex.